# Spark missing column when write and read back

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am creating a dataset and writing it to s3 in a directory structure `${BasePath}/y=2107/m=11/d=16/` in **parquet** format. After I creates current day data and writes it to s3, I need to read back the data for last 10 days.

I can do this is 2 ways,

1st Approach :  Write current day data to s3, read rest of the 9 days data and do a union, like

```
dataset.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
              .format(sourceConfig.format).save(getWriteBasePath(sourceConfig.sourcePath
              , replaceDate))
newDf = spark.read.parquet("path1",...,"path9").union(dataset)
```

2nd Approach:  Write current day data to s3, and read all 10 days data back again. Something like :

```
     dataset.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
          .format(sourceConfig.format).save(getWriteBasePath(sourceConfig.sourcePath
          , replaceDate))
    newDf = spark.read.parquet("path1",...,"path10")
```

1st approach is working without any issues **but very slow compared to 2nd approach**. But with the second approach, some of the columns from current day's are getting null values after I read the complete data back to spark. I verified that the current day's data which is written is proper.

I am not able to figure out why this is happening. I am creating spark context with following properties :

```
sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version", "2")
      sparkSession.sparkContext.getConf.set("spark.hadoop.parquet.enable.summary-metadata", "false")
      sparkSession.sparkContext.getConf.set("spark.sql.parquet.mergeSchema", "false")
      sparkSession.sparkContext.getConf.set("spark.sql.parquet.filterPushdown", "true")
      sparkSession.sparkContext.getConf.set("spark.sql.hive.metastorePartitionPruning", "true")
```

Comment: _"Some of the columns..."_?? Which columns are getting null values?

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt Out of some 20 columns column 15 and column 16 values are all null.. All other columns have proper values

Comment: logically the first approach should work faster as you are reading less data from the disk..may be the second approach is working faster because of loading just null values for those 2 cols. What is the size of the data you are dealing with. if data of those 2 columns is of significant size, your second approach is running fast as it is not loading this data.

Comment: @Phoenix Total data size is around 70 Gb in parquet with snappy compression. And that 2 columns are just text columns with max 30-40 characters.

Comment: Might help someone with similar issue:
If the columns being used for partitioning the data frame have null values(like "day" or "month" column), try adding option("basePath", basePath).

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to cache the current data in one dataframe and read all past 9 days into another dataframe. Now that you have all data in memory.. your execution should be must faster. The moment we write to s3 (as its an action) the entire DAG created will be flushed and thats the reason your first approach is real slow.

Comment: I am actually caching it.. but still take 5 mins more than the 2nd approach